# Asus RT-AC88U routing blocked by firewall

Tags: iptables, firewall, routing, router

### The context:

I have the following configuration:

[image: router configuration]

The `Main router` is my internet provider's property, I can't modify its configuration.
The `Personal Router` is my Asus RT-AC88U router, I can modify its configuration.

I want to access my  **192.168.1.*n*** servers from my `Computer`, which is on a different subnet (192.168.0.0).

I added a route to my `Computer` configuration using the following command:

```
route add 192.168.1.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.3
```

With the firewall disabled on the `Personal Router` everything works fine.

### The Problem:

However, as soon as I enable it, it drops every package, here is an example of the logs:

```
Aug  2 19:24:41 kernel: DROP IN=eth0 OUT=br0 SRC=192.168.0.2 DST=192.168.1.30 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=127 ID=1369 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=58785 DPT=80 SEQ=2324253310 ACK=0 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40103030801010402)
```

I tried logging through ssh to the `Personal Router` and adding the following rules:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 192.168.0.2 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 192.168.0.2 -j ACCEPT
```

([From this post](https://serverfault.com/a/163123))
However, it did not solve the problem.
Restarting iptables using `service restart_firewall` dropped the custom configuration.

What should I do? Disabling the firewall is not an option since the wifi is enabled.

### Edit - The solution:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.0.2 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: It sounds like you are using it as a NAT router, not simply routing. I'm not sure why your company would sign a contract with its ISP where your company cannot use its own router as the main router, nor why you would run a company with a router designed for residential networking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try instead:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.0.2 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

As you found by yourself, -I is needed to put the rule to the top of the FORWARD chain. Please note that this way you skip any security relying on the firewall.

Comment: I did try the FORWARD approach as well but did not save the exact commands. I tried yours but it did not work neither. 

I edited the question to add more details about the default `iptables` configuration

Comment: Changing the command to -I instead of -A worked ... I should have payed more attentions to the options. Thank you :)